# How can I get data for the earliest time on a specific day?

Tags: sql, django, python-3.x, sqlite, django-forms

For example there is a field called `date_published`. How can I get the earliest data on a specific day? Let say, I want the earliest `date_published` for today... I expect the document returned is the closest one to 00:00:00 dated today.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a query for this column in ascending order and put a where clause for this column to be current date and then select the first record only.

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE_NAME] 
WHERE CURDATE() = DATE(date_published) 
ORDER BY date_published ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't particularly follow your way. But it gives me pointer to use Django data aggregate.